# Sublist in Lisp

Tags: loops, recursion, indexing, lisp, sublist

Im having trouble creating a sublist in lisp. My task is to write a function that takes a list and two indexes from and to, and returns "sublist" whose elements are the elements within from and to indexes. I am only allowed to use the functions cdr, car, cons, list and append. Here is an example of how the output of the code should look like.

sublist '(1 6 12) 2 3)
output: (6 12)

Comment: "_I'm having trouble creating a sublist in lisp._" -- What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

```
(sublist '(1 6 12 15) 2 3)
```

has the same result as

```
(sublist '(6 12 15) 1 2)
```

When you reach 1 for start index, you can check the value of end while consing elements; be careful with empty lists too. The previous expression can be rewritten:

```
(cons 6 (sublist '(12 15) 1 1))
```

and

```
(cons 6 (cons 12 (sublist '(15) 1 0)))
```

finally

```
(cons 6 (cons 12 nil))
```

More precisely, here is a trace of execution:

```
USER> (sub '(1 2 3 4 5) 2 4)
  0: (SUB (1 2 3 4 5) 2 4)
    1: (SUB (2 3 4 5) 1 3)
      2: (SUB (3 4 5) 1 2)
        3: (SUB (4 5) 1 1)
          4: (SUB (5) 1 0)
          4: SUB returned NIL
        3: SUB returned (4)
      2: SUB returned (3 4)
    1: SUB returned (2 3 4)
  0: SUB returned (2 3 4)
(2 3 4)
```