# Common Lisp Returning members of a list from one index to another

Tags: common-lisp

This is what ive tried till now, but im getting some errors and im kinda confused

What is want to do is:

For example calling (sub-list((2 3 4 5 6) 2 3))
will result in a recursive function like

*x* = 1,(sub-list('(3 4 5 6) 2 3))

*x* = 2, cons (car ls) (sub-list((4 5 6) 2 3))

*x* = 3 ,cons (car ls) (sub-list((5 6) 2 3))

*x* = 4 , nil since x is now greater than to.

and it should backtrack to return (4 5) something like that

```
(defvar *x* 1)      

(defun sub-list(ls from to)
    (cond
        ((<= *x* from) (sub-list((cdr ls) from to)))
        ((<= from *x* to)
            (let (*x* (+ *x* 1))
                cons a (sub-list((cdr ls) from to)))))
        ((> *x* to) nil)))
```

Comment: I don't think `(sub-list((2 3 4 5 6) 2 3))` is legal Lisp.

Comment: Can you explain what `sub-list` is supposed to do, independent of *how* it does it?

Comment: Sorry i forgot the apostrophe
(sub-list('(2 3 4 5 6) 2 3)) is supposed to return index 2 to 3 of the list which would be (3 4) in this case (index starts from 1)

Comment: Note that `(sub-list lst a b)` = `(sub-list (cdr lst) (- a 1) (- b 1))` (assuming a>1).

Comment: "_... I'm getting some errors.... _" -- what are those errors? Your question says `(sub-list('(2 3 4 5 6) 2 3))` --> `(4 5)`, but your last comment says that `(3 4)` should be returned: which is it? The posted code will not compile; is that the error? If so, check your parentheses. You probably should not be using a dynamic variable for `*x*` here.

Comment: You seem to have general confusion about where you need to put parentheses in Lisp. You don't put parentheses around all the arguments to a function like you do in other languages.

Comment: And you're missing the `(` before `cons`.

Comment: The general pattern is that `f(a, b, c)` in other languages becomes `(f a b c)` in Lisp.

Comment: So before you can worry about algorithms, you need to get the basic syntax right.

Comment: I see thank you very much

Comment: that being said, the algorithm looks good (see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/64490030/124319)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general recommendation, using a global and special variable to track internal state is not recommended.

As @coredump pointed out in a comment, [Sublist in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64490030/124319) has an answer pointing in the right direction.

To avoid the special variable, you can (in principle) change the start and end index (as pointed out by @ScottHunter).

This means that you can change your "start accumulating" from `(<= *x* from)` to `(<= from 0)` and your "end accumulating" to `(<= to 0)`.

This also requires changing each recursive call to be something like `(sub-list (cdr list) (1- from) (1- to))` (and gets rid of the bug in the initial skip phase, where you are not incrementing `*x*`).